# find longest contiguous sequence of integers in an unsorted array without hashmap

Tags: java, algorithm, methods, performance

Using Java, I have to create a program that takes an ordered set of numbers and returns the length of the longest consecutive number sequence.  For example, for the set (1,18,12,6,8,7,13,2,3,4,9,10) the method should return 5 because the longest consecutive sequence is (6,7,8,9,10).

it should be as efficient as possible, you can't use hashmaps, actually for just iterations I'm guessing the best option will be sorting the array (nlogn) and then running through the array once more (n) will be the best option?

Comment: Doesn't sorting the array conflict with your goal?

Comment: 6,7,8,9,10 do not appear in that order in the given array.  Does that not matter?

Comment: You can get some speedup by tracking what the current longest size is, and then doing a quick check to see if the sorted array advanced ahead could possibly be the correct value (I.E. if longest sequence is 5, and my current number at `i` is 1, then if `i+5` is no `6`, I can just skip ahead to `i+5`.

Comment: @aliteralmind No, unless you can do it in (n) running time or better without sorting, and all the examples I found were with hashmaps so I guess it's not possible?

Comment: @DonRoby I imagine it's in the `once it is sorted`, otherwise you're totally correct.

Comment: Is the answer for the input set of numbers really 5 .. I thought you had to use the original order of the number set .. so that 3 would be the answer (for 2,3,4)

Comment: @DonRoby no, it doesn't matter

Comment: @aruisdante, even if it's unsorted it should return the same value

Comment: Our point is that `(6,7,8,9,10)` is not a consecutive sequence in the unsorted array. It only would be in a sorted version of the input array.

Comment: @aruisdante It *is* a contiguous sequence of integers though, and I think this is what OP means. Find `l` and `r`, such that `r-l+1` is maximized and all integers in the range `[l,r]` appear in the array

Comment: Correct, but you're producing it out of the input array, which would also assume there are no duplicates or specify if duplicates break the sequence. The OP needs to clarify if the question is 'largest consecutive sequence you can make out of the numbers contained in the input array', or 'largest consecutive sequence present in the input array'.

Comment: yes, it must be sorted else if you want the same result without sorting it will go with the complexity of `n^(n-1)` as you have to check each element with other n-1 elements.

Comment: @ADi that makes no sense at all. I guess you mean n*(n-1).

Comment: And the answer is...yes the way you've come up with is a fast way. If this is an assignment, I guess it's time to go write the code.

Comment: If the range of numbers is reasonably small I'd use a bitset.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a large input that an O(n log n) algorithm would be too slow and you want an algorithm without using hashmap, you could use radix sort and still get the same O(n) performance.

Radix Sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Basically it sorts the input by applying bucket sort on lowest k(I usually use 4 or 8) bits, and then on the next lowest k bits, and so on, until all of the bits are sorted on.

The code would be like below(Sorry I'm not so familiar with Java so it may contain some mistakes, but I hope you can get what I mean.)

```
static final int RADIX_POW2=4;//you could also use 8 if you want it 
                              //twice as fast and 16 times as space taking.
static final int RADIX=1<<RADIX_POW2;

static void radix_sort_part(int[] input, ArrayList<int>[] buckets, int shift){
    for(int x:input) buckets[x>>shift & (RADIX-1)].add(x);
    int count=0;
    for(ArrayList<int> bucket:buckets){
        for(int x:bucket)
            input[count++]=x;
        bucket.clear();
    }
}
static void radix_sort_full(int[] input){
    ArrayList<int>[] buckets=new ArrayList<int>[RADIX];
    for(int i=0;i<RADIX;i++)
        buckets[i]=new ArrayList<int>();
    //I'm performing radix sorts on full 32 bits, but if the range of 
    //your inputs are smaller, you only need to perform it on the range.
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(int)*8/RADIX_POW2;i++)
        radix_sort_part(input,buckets,i*RADIX_POW2);       
}
static int find_max_consecutive(int[] input){
    radix_sort_full(input);
    int maxconsecutive=1;
    int currentconsecutive=1;
    for(int i=1; i<input.size();i++){
        if(input[i]=input[i-1]+1)currentconsecutive++; 
        if(currentconsecutive>maxconsecutive)maxconsecutive=currentconsecutive;
    }
    return maxconsecutive;
}
```

However, I think this algorithm is slow if you have many relatively small inputs and you need to solve this problem again and again.
And for a large input, this algorithm could be as memory-consuming as hashmap and not as fast. So if I was asked to choose, I would rather use hashmap.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that radix sort takes time that is proportional to how many times it has to perform bucket sort, that is, ( (number of bits of the integers)/RADIX_POW2 ).
So the exact time complexity of this algorithm is O(dn), where d is (number of bits of the integers)/RADIX_POW2.
This means that if you want to use algorithm to long numbers, it takes twice as long, and if you want to use this to BigInteger or String or something like that, it would take as long as how the integers(strings) are big.

Comment: Radix sort is not O(n), but rather O(d·n) for n keys which have d or fewer digits. While d may be considered constant when dealing with Java primitive integral types, you should probably at least note this.

Comment: @Dukeling Thanks, I should have mentioned that.